# Передача переменных между окнами в python kivy

Tags: python, kivy

У меня есть глобальная переменная ans, и мне надо изменив её в MenuScreen, вывести в SettingScreen

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_string("""
<MenuScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        TextInput:
            id: word
            multiline: False
        Button:
            text: 'дальше'
            on_press: 
                root.pars(word.text)
                root.manager.current = 'settings'



<SettingsScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
           # text: и тут должен быть ans
        Button:
            text: "Назад"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
""")


class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def pars(self, text):
        global ans
        ans = text

    pass


class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    global ans
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name='settings'))


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Изначально всё не верно! Использовать глобальную переменную да еще и в Kivy - это, мягко говоря, глупость.

Comment: А каким образом можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

Builder.load_string("""
<MenuScreen>

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        TextInput:
            id: word
            multiline: False

        Button:
            text: 'дальше'
            on_press: 
                root.pars(word.text)
                root.manager.current = 'settings'


<SettingsScreen>

    BoxLayout:

        Label:
            id: label

        Button:
            text: "Назад"
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
""")


class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def pars(self, text):
        sm.get_screen('settings').ids.label.text = text


class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass


sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name='settings'))


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test(App):
    var = None

    def build(self):
        return widget
```

Теперь переменная `var` доступна всегда и везде:

```
Label:
    text: str(app.var)


class MyScreen(Screen):
    def get_var(self):
        from kivy.app import App

        return App.get_running_app().var
```

Или:

```
<MyScreen>
    var: app.var


class MyScreen(Screen):
    var = ObjectProperty()

    def get_var(self):
        return self.var
```

Или:

```
<MyScreen>
    app: app


class MyScreen(Screen):
    app = ObjectProperty()

    def get_var(self):
        return self.app.var
```

Comment: Извиняюсь за глупую просьбу, но можете ли вы изменить конкретно мой код, а то я совсем не понял что именно мне нужно изменить.

Comment: А я чей код, по-твоему, изменил!?